# NameError: uninitialized constant Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, black-box-testing

I am a beginner of Ruby on Rails and I am doing a online assignment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwvt4e6DQqn4ZjgwdzFGazZBZVE/view

repository: https://github.com/jhu-ep-coursera/fullstack-course1-module3

However, I encountered some problems (step 5 of getting started in the file) when I tried to get started.

The error I got is shown below:

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/recipes_app_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist

NameError:
uninitialized constant Capybara
# ./spec/recipes_app_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'  
No examples found.


Finished in 0.00034 seconds (files took 0.23609 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples
```

How can I fix this problem? Many Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

It means that Capybara is not available in your ruby on rails app.  Look for a file called "Gemfile" inside your RoR app, and then look inside the Gemfile for a line that says:

```
gem 'capybara'
```

If you don't see it then you will need to add it.  Once you've done that, go to the console, go to the root directory of your RoR app and run

```
bundle install
```

Once you've done that, in your test helper file you will need to add the line

```
require 'capybara/rails'
```

There is a lot of information about Capybara available on their github page located here:  https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara